# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ds-math-sub-underflow'

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js, contract, uniswap

While test deploying UniswapV2Swap Contract the following code is generating the following error `"ProviderError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ds-math-sub-underflow' "`

The deploying javascript code is:

```
describe("UniswapV2SwapExamples", function () {
    let uniswapV2;
    before(async function () {
        const UniswapV2 = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapV2SwapExamples");
        uniswapV2 = await UniswapV2.deploy();
        // await uniswapV2.deployed();
        console.log("UniswapV2SwapExamples is deployed to ", uniswapV2.target);
    });
it("swapMultiHopExactAmountOutshould perform a Swap DAI -> WETH -> USDC", async function () {
        getBalance();
        const amountOutDesired = ethers.parseUnits("1000");
        const amountInMax = ethers.parseUnits("1400");
        
        const approveTx = await daiTokenIN.connect(signer).approve(uniswapV2.target, amountInMax);
        approveTx.wait();
        
        // const currentNonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(signer.getAddress());
        // { nonce: currentNonce }

        const tx2 = await uniswapV2.swapMultiHopExactAmountOut(amountOutDesired, amountInMax);
        tx2.wait();
        getBalance();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using connect(signer) solve the issue.

```
const tx2 = await uniswapV2.connect(signer).swapMultiHopExactAmountOut(amountOutDesired, amountInMax);
```